# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider $uibModal

Tags: angularjs

I new in AngularJs.I have error

```
 Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provide
```

angularjs

```
 var App = angular.module('StartModule', ["ui.bootstrap"]);
 App.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function ($scope,    $uibModal) {
$scope.test = function () {}});
```

error appears when I add $uibModal

Comment: may i know angularjs version ?

Comment: have you injected "ui-bootstrap" related entries in index.html ?

Comment: <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script> This should be the included if you are using bower dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Inject **$uibModalInstance** dependency. And use events like **$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel')**.

```js
var App = angular.module('StartModule', ["ui.bootstrap"]);
 App.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope,    $uibModalInstance) {
$scope.test = function () {}});
```

Comment: @user5555160 may I know which angular ui bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: * Version: 1.3.1 - 2016-04-05